# What are your main concerns when getting your car wrapped with custom-patterns?

Tags: body

Let's say you're getting your car custom wrapped.
What would be your top concern when hiring someone to do the job?
This would be a key area to filter when picking a service provider.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thing I look for when I am picking *any* service provider is reputation.  Usually you can find a provider that is recommended by their customers.

For custom car wraps I would look for quality of the designs and the wrap itself.  I would also look for durability.

As for the application of the wrap, http://roadragedesigns.com/installation.html has some good examples of what to look for. Just as a disclaimer, I'm not trying to recommend them for the install, but the web page has some good pictures of what you *don't* want your wrap to look like.